# Import Project from IntelliJ IDEA to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I was only able to find guides on how to import an Eclipse project into Android Studio. But I am not using Eclipse, I am using IntelliJ IDEA.

How do I generate the new Gradle build files for my project?

EDIT:
To clarify. I know how to setup Gradle manually. But that's not what I am asking for. The question is: Am I able to let the Android SDK generate the Gradle files for me? Like the ADT does... But since I'm not using Eclipse, I don't have access to the export feature of ADT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay for everyone who needs to do this:

It's not possible.

But if you want to create the neccessary Gradle build file manually. Here it is: https://gist.github.com/Goddchen/5600345

Comment: Could you finally import your project from IntelliJ IDEA to Android Studio? If yes, could you pleas lead me how can I do that?

Comment: can you plz say how to setup gradle manually for intellij project to make it run in android studio

Answer (score 1):

Have you started Android Studio yet? Because importing IDEA Projects is one of the possible selections you can choose in the beginning.

If you passed that initial state already, just go to File -> Import Project and select the folder of your project that you want to import. The rest is straight forward and pretty bullet proof as both are basically IDEA :D

Comment: well, then I have my IDEA project in Android Studio, as an IDEA project. No Gradle stuff, nothing... Just a simple IDEA project as it used to be...

Comment: Have you tried a simple search on the IDEA site? http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/tag/gradle/ there are a bunch of articles to show the basics.

Comment: Sure, I have used the Gradle build system for Android in the past. I know how to create the files manually. But that obviously wasn't my question.

Comment: You can import your settings from IDEA as well. If your setup already had gradle set up, than the imported project should have the same in the studio... Otherwise be way more specific...

Comment: I want to import a project from intellij to android studio but have it as an android project. This answer simple opens it as a java project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to "Import Project (Maven, Gradle, ...)" and then select not the folder, but 'settings.gradle' instead. Then Android Studio will do everything by itself.